# afterRender threw an error in 'c:TestLWC' [Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am using the below code to make a call to apex method on page load and validate some response. I am getting error

**afterRender threw an error in 'c:TestLWC' [Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]**

```
@track recorddetails;
      @wire(getRecordDetails, { recordId: "$recordId" })
      validateresponse({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
        } else if (data) {
          recorddetails= JSON.parse(data);
        }

      }
```

HTML

```
 <template if:true={recorddetails.data}>
   <template for:each={recorddetails.data} for:item="rr">
      <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
         <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" size="6">
            <p class="slds-text-title_bold">Owner:</p>
            {rr.Account__r.Name}
         </lightning-layout-item>
      </lightning-layout>
   </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set a default value:

```
@track recorddetails = { data: [] }
```

And also, you generally don't need to parse the data. In addition, you need to use `this` to set the correct value:

```
this.recorddetails = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is two problem in code.

- First one @sfdcfox has mentioned about putting this
  `this.recorddetails = data`;
- Second one is template code -  `<template if:true={recorddetails.data}>` looks like recorddetails is null and you try to access data on it so it is throwing `[Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]`. Change this to `<template if:true={recorddetails}>` should resolve issue.